# Service for generating faked objects

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, generics, interface

I'm using the [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) library to mock up some data for testing.

This is my main method demonstrating how the faking service should be used:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFakerService r = new FakerService();

        var dogs = r.Generate<Dog>(10);
        var customers = r.Generate<Customer>(10);
        var cats = r.Generate<Cat>(10);
    }
}
```

A Dog class looks like:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsGoodBoy => true;
}
```

My interface simply defines the only method the service should expose:

```
public interface IFakerService
{
    IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(int count) where T : class;
}
```

And the service itself:

```
public class FakerService : IFakerService
{
    // Can we do better than <Type, object> ?
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _fakers;

    public FakerService()
    {
        _fakers = InitialiseFakers();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(int count) where T : class
    {
        var faker = GetFaker<T>();
        return faker.Generate(count);
    }

    // Types which can be faked are registered here
    private Dictionary<Type, object> InitialiseFakers()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, object>()
        {
            {typeof(Dog), new DogFaker().GetFaker()},
            {typeof(Cat), new CatFaker().GetFaker()},
            {typeof(Customer), new CustomerFaker().GetFaker()}
        };
    }

    private Faker<T> GetFaker<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (!_fakers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Type: {typeof(T).FullName} not registered with FakerService");
        }
        var faker = (Faker<T>)_fakers[typeof(T)];
        return faker;
    }
}
```

The interface for Faker objects:

```
public interface IFaker<T> where T : class
{
    Faker<T> GetFaker();
}
```

And one of the implementations:

```
public class DogFaker : IFaker<Dog>
{
    public Faker<Dog> GetFaker()
    {
        return new Faker<Dog>()
            .RuleFor(dog => dog.Name, f => f.Name.FirstName(Name.Gender.Male))
            .RuleFor(dog => dog.IsGoodBoy, f => f.Random.Bool());
    }
}
```

Overall I'm quite happy with how it looks - the parts that I was wondering if I could improve on are:

```
private Dictionary<Type, object> _fakers;

...

return new Dictionary<Type, object>()
{
    {typeof(Dog), new DogFaker().GetFaker()}
}

...

var faker = (Faker<T>)_fakers[typeof(T)];
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: IsGoodBoy should ALWAYS return true >:(

Comment: This looks like a cache. Are you building one? What problem does this solve? Currently I think it's easier to just call the `Faker` APIs when you need them. I'm not sure how this service helps.

Comment: We want to use faked objects in different areas across our solution - in tests, seeding etc.

Comment: This approach stops us from needing to define the setup rules repeatedly or the ability to add parameters to the fakers to come up with a particular set of mocked parameters

Comment: @StevenEccles I guess it's just an example ;-]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public interface IFaker<T> where T : class
> {
>     Faker<T> GetFaker();
> }
> ```

I don't think you need this interface and the additional call to `GetFaker`. Instead you can derive your class from the `Faker<T>` and use the constructor to set everything up:

```
public class DogFaker : Faker<Dog>
{
    public DogFaker()
    {
        RuleFor(dog => dog.Name, f => f.Name.FirstName(Name.Gender.Male));
        RuleFor(dog => dog.IsGoodBoy, f => f.Random.Bool());
    }   
}
```

---

> ```
> private Faker<T> GetFaker<T>() where T : class
> {
>   if (!_fakers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
>   {
>       throw new ArgumentException($"Type: {typeof(T).FullName} not registered with FakerService");
>   }
>   var faker = (Faker<T>)_fakers[typeof(T)];
>   return faker;
> }
> ```

In this case it would be much clener to query the dictionary only once with `TryGetValue` if you are going to use the value anyway rather then doing it twice, once with `ContainsKey` and then with the `[]` indexer. At the same time you can tun it into a ternary operator `?:`:

```
private Faker<T> GetFaker<T>() where T : class
{
    return
        _fakers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var faker)
            ? (Faker<T>)faker
            : throw new ArgumentException($"Type: {typeof(T).FullName} not registered with FakerService");
}
```

---

Since ´InitialiseFakers´ does not require any instance data I suggest making it `static`. I like the way you created this initializer. Instead of letting it set the `_fakers` dictionary you return it as a result and assign it in the construtor. This way it's much cleaner and all the initialization-assignment stays inside the construtor so a big plus for that.

---

> ```
> // Can we do better than <Type, object> ?
> private Dictionary<Type, object> _fakers;
> ```

I'm afraid we cannot because `Faker<T>` isn't derived from any other collection-friendly interface. All you have is:

> ```
> public class Faker<T> : IFakerTInternal, ILocaleAware, IRuleSet<T> where T : class
> ```

and this is not very useful so `object` is the only possible generalisation in this case. But this isn't that bad. It's an object so it doesn't cost you a penny to cast it. But sure, some general interface would be nice.